# How to get data(attribute)-Open file in text format for reading line-by-line (OOP JAVA)

Tags: java, file, oop, attributes

how?
enter code here
Split the read line into parts;
Create a brand from input data(parts);
Add the brand to this list;

```
     ArrayList<String> str1 = new ArrayList<>();
    loadFromFile(file, str1);    
    for (String string : str1) {
        String[] str = string.split(",");
        //EG line of file: B7-2018, BMW 730Li (2018), Harman Kardon, 3.749
        String id,name,sound;
        double price;

        id = str[0];
        name = str[1];
        price = Double.valueOf(str[3]);
         sound = str[2];
        Brands brand = new Brands(id, name, sound, price);
        this.add(brand);  /// this is arraylist of Brands (extends ArrayList Brands)
        //error code: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 
        //I do not understand this
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to read the file with a `Scanner` and use `String.split` on your line to get your data

Comment: Can you be more specific? 
How to read the file with a Scanner and use String.split ?
EG for me ,plsss

Comment: i think ,my problem isn't  read the file that is split and release to arraylist . rerror code is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException